# Cronjob execute problem - doesn't execute the controller/method

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to create a cron job and execute the cron job through the terminal, but when I execute - php index.php hello(controller) greet(method) Glen(parameter) , prints home page. Any idea what can cause problem like this?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page Not Found</title>
<meta name="description" content="Please find what you're looking for by using the main menu">
```

Comment: Do you mean you run on the CLI: `php index.php hello greet Glen`?  If it prints the home page, what is the 404 HTML you have included here?  Does visiting `http://your-site/index.php/hello/greet/Glen` in your browser also show the home page?

Comment: When vistit http://your-site/index.php/hello/greet/Glen I only get Page Not Found.

Comment: I am just guessing but I think you also see 404/page not found when running from CLI (not the home page, as you've described in the question). The HTML you have included here is the 404 page, not the home page.  So it means that actually your routing is not working, this is not a problem with CLI ...

Comment: Changed the route and the also there was a typo...thank you for pointing me in the right direction.